# When is the group $C^*$-algebra of a locally compact group an AF-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, group-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, locally-compact-groups

It is known that the group $C^*$-algebra of a compact group is an AF-algebra. I want to know if given a non-compact locally compact group $G$, does there exist conditions on $G$ which imply that the (full or reduced) group $C^*$-algebra of $G$ is an AF-algebra?

Also, are there any known examples of non-compact locally compact groups whose group $C^*$-algebra is an AF-algebra, and the group $C^*$-algebra has been computed? Examples where the group is non-discrete would be of most interest.

Comment: The C*-algebra of a compact group is the direct sum of matrix algebras, so it is AF. Conversely, if $C^{\ast}(G)$ is AF, then it has real rank zero. By a theorem of Kaniuth, this would imply that $G$ is compact.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan The result by Kaniuth that you mention only holds for connected locally compact groups from what I see (looking at his 1993 article). Has this result been generalised to non-connected groups?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan What is the title of Kaniuth's 1993 article in question ?